# Converting and an arma::mat adjacency matrix into an igraph graph in C (Rcpp)

Tags: type-conversion, igraph, rcpp, armadillo

I use Armadillo objects in some (Rcpp) code where I work with matrices.

The matrices are adjacency matrices and I need to quickly compute the components of the underlying network and though I could do this via `igraph`.

But I fail already at converting the adjacency matrix into something that can be used with `igraph`.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <igraph-0.7.1\include\igraph.h>

using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec component_membership(const mat& adjacencymatrix) {
  igraph_t  g;
  igraph_adjacency(&g,&adjacencymatrix,IGRAPH_ADJ_DIRECTED);
  // here is more code that is immaterial to my problem
}
```

On compilation it complains

```
 cannot convert 'const mat* {aka const arma::Mat<double>*}' to  
  'igraph_matrix_t*' for argument '2' to 
  'int igraph_adjacency(igraph_t*, igraph_matrix_t*, igraph_adjacency_t)'
```

I understand why that is the case: I believe `igraph_matrix_t` and `arma::matrix` must be fundamentally different data types. How can I convert, i.e., but how do i fix this easily?

Comment: Not sure what the type of `adjacencymatrix` is but it looks like the function expects a pointer to a matrix and you pass a matrix. How is `adjacencymatrix` declared?

Comment: e.g. like `arma::mat  adjacencymatrix=arma::zeros<mat>(10,10);`

Comment: I don't think the pointer is the issue, when I change the call to `igraph_adjacency(&g,&adjacencymatrix,IGRAPH_ADJ_DIRECTED);` I get ` cannot convert const mat* {aka const arma::Mat<double>*} to  
  igraph_matrix_t* for argument 2 ....`

Comment: This certainly doesn't look like C. It appears to be pure C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected, `igraph_matrix_t` and `arma::matrix` are completely different types. The [igraph documentation](https://igraph.org/c/doc/ch07.html#igraph-Matrices) lists no methods that would make use of a C array for constructing an `igraph_matrix_t`, so I think one has to do it by hand. Something like this might work (totally untested!):

```cpp
igraph_matrix_t *m;
int rc = igraph_matrix_init(m, mat.n_rows, mat.n_cols);
for (unsigned long j = 0; j < mat.n_cols; ++j)
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < mat.n_rows; ++i)
        igraph_matrix_set(m, i, j, mat(i, j));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ralf_Stubner's suggestion I ended up using the following code. Not sure it is smart, I thought I'd share it anyways

```
void armamat_to_igraph_matrix(const mat &x_in, igraph_matrix_t *x_out) {
  igraph_matrix_init(x_out, x_in.n_rows, x_in.n_cols);
  for (unsigned long j = 0; j < x_in.n_cols; ++j)
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < x_in.n_rows; ++i)
      igraph_matrix_set(x_out, i, j, x_in(i, j));        
  return;
}
void igraph_vector_to_armauvec(const igraph_vector_t *x_in, uvec  &x_out) {
  x_out = uvec(igraph_vector_size(x_in));
  for (unsigned long j = 0; j < igraph_vector_size(x_in); ++j)
    x_out(j) = igraph_vector_e(x_in,j);        
  return;
}
void igraph_vector_to_armavec(const igraph_vector_t *x_in, vec  &x_out) {
  x_out = vec(igraph_vector_size(x_in));
  for (unsigned long j = 0; j < igraph_vector_size(x_in); ++j)
    x_out(j) = igraph_vector_e(x_in,j);        
  return;
}
```